# Django "CSRF cookie not set" error when calling server from cross origin frontend

Tags: django

I have a Vue application locally and a Vite dev server hosting the application. I am using a [Vite ngrok plugin](https://github.com/aphex/vite-plugin-ngrok) for testing resulting in an ngrok URL like the following:

```
http://a709-73-72-42-7.ngrok-free.app
```

I also have a Django application running locally on port 8000 servicing requests from the frontend (not hosting the frontend). To demonstrate the error I'm seeing, I have a login page that is submitting a POST request to the Django backend using the `fetch` method:

```
async function login(username, password) {
    const token = await _getCsrfToken();
    if (!token) {
        throw new Error('CSRF token not available');
    }

    const resp = await fetch(`${API_URL}/account/login`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': token,
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    });

    return resp;

}


async function _getCsrfToken() {
    const resp = await fetch(`${API_URL}/account/csrf`, {
        credentials: 'include',
    });

    return resp.headers.get('x-csrftoken');
}
```

Notice the `_getCsrfToken` calls another endpoint, `account/csrf` to get a CSRF token from the Django backend.

On the backend, the `account/csrf` is handled by:

```
def csrf(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    resp = HttpResponse()
    resp['X-CSRFToken'] = get_token(request)

    return resp
```

And the `account/login` endpoint is handled by:

```
@require_POST
def login(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    ... do stuff to authenticate ...
```

The call to `account/csrf` is successful and has the following response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://a709-73-72-42-7.ngrok-free.app
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, X-CSRFToken
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Server: daphne
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=xByLUsqLlewLCTNDIyYD08TPQcK9A72J; expires=Sat, 18 Jan 2025 21:14:17 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Cookie, origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Csrftoken: aEO3Gy83Vlgj4OpgDtu8hrWlZ5WbPRG7x5cEqQoE6pCUwx2JbRiB7pF0F7wafOyG
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

(Notice the `X-Csrftoken` and the `csrftoken` in the `Set-Cookie` header are different.)

However, if I look at the cookies in the developer tabs, the cookie is not set (why?). When the `account/login` request is made, the result is a 403 forbidden being returned by the Django backend with the following error:

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.

Help

Reason given for failure:

    CSRF cookie not set.
```

The request headers of the `account/login` request are:

```
POST /account/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://a709-73-72-42-7.ngrok-free.app/
Content-Type: application/json
X-CSRFToken: aEO3Gy83Vlgj4OpgDtu8hrWlZ5WbPRG7x5cEqQoE6pCUwx2JbRiB7pF0F7wafOyG
Content-Length: 49
Origin: http://a709-73-72-42-7.ngrok-free.app
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

On the Django side, I'm using `django-cors-headers` (with `corsheaders` added to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list and `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` middleware added to the top of the `MIDDLEWARE` list) and the following configuration in `settings.py`:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://localhost:5173', 'https://*.ngrok-free.app', 'http://*.ngrok-free.app']

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ['Content-Type', 'X-CSRFToken']
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

It seems to be something related to running the frontend through ngrok, because if I just run the frontend as `localhost:5173`, things work fine.

For what it's worth, I'm loosely basing the above off of the example found in https://github.com/duplxey/django-spa-cookie-auth/tree/master/django_react_cross_origin.

What am I missing?